# Read sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I want to read a **sparse matrix**. When I am building **ngrams** using **scikit learn**. Its **transform()** gives output in sparse matrix. I want to read that matrix without doing **todense()**.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
document = ['john guy','nice guy']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(document)
transformer = vectorizer.transform(document)
print transformer
```

**Output :**

```
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 3)    1
  (1, 4)    1
```

How can I **read** this output to get its **values**. I need value at **(0,0), (0,1)** and so on and save into **list**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation for this `transform` method says it returns a sparse matrix, but doesn't specify the kind.  Different kinds let you access the data in different ways, but it is easy to convert one to another.  Your print display is the typical `str` for a sparse matrix.

An equivalent matrix can be generated with:

```
from scipy import sparse
i=[0,0,0,1,1,1]
j=[0,1,2,0,3,4]
A=sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones_like(j),(i,j)))
print(A)
```

producing:

```
  (0, 0)        1
  (0, 1)        1
  (0, 2)        1
  (1, 0)        1
  (1, 3)        1
  (1, 4)        1
```

A `csr` type can be indexed like a dense matrix:

```
In [32]: A[0,0]
Out[32]: 1    
In [33]: A[0,3]
Out[33]: 0
```

Internally the `csr` matrix stores its data in `data`, `indices`, `indptr`, which is convenient for calculation, but a bit obscure.  Convert it to `coo` format to get data that looks just like your input:

```
In [34]: A.tocoo().row
Out[34]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)

In [35]: A.tocoo().col
Out[35]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Or you can convert it to a `dok` type, and access that data like a dictionary:

```
A.todok().keys()
#  dict_keys([(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 3), (1, 0), (0, 2), (1, 4)])
A.todok().items()
```

produces: (Python3 here)

```
dict_items([((0, 1), 1), 
            ((0, 0), 1), 
            ((1, 3), 1), 
            ((1, 0), 1), 
            ((0, 2), 1), 
            ((1, 4), 1)])
```

The `lil` format stores the data as 2 lists of lists, one with the data (all 1s in this example), and the other with the row indices.

Or do you what to 'read' the data in some other way?

Answer (score 4):

This is a [SciPy CSR matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). To convert this to (row, col, value) triples, the easiest option is to convert to [COO format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html), then get the triples from that:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import rand
>>> X = rand(100, 100, format='csr')
>>> X
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> zip(X.row, X.col, X.data)[:10]
[(1, 78, 0.73843533223380842),
 (1, 91, 0.30943772717074158),
 (2, 35, 0.52635078317400608),
 (4, 75, 0.34667509458006551),
 (5, 30, 0.86482318943934389),
 (7, 74, 0.46260571098933323),
 (8, 75, 0.74193890941716234),
 (9, 72, 0.50095749482583696),
 (9, 80, 0.85906284644174613),
 (11, 66, 0.83072142899400137)]
```

(Note that the output is sorted.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data` and `indices` as:

```
>>> indices=transformer.toarray()
>>> indices
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
>>> values=transformer.data
>>> values
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Sorry, I have mentioned in the question that I don't want to use **todense()** to convert the **sparse matrix into ordinary matrix**. Any other solution.

Comment: @Nikkz, Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully. I've provided some methods of reading data. Hope it helps.